# What are the rules for scope in java?

Tags: java, scope, conditional-statements

I'm hoping that someone can explain to me the java rules for scope in the context of these two examples:

Example 1 (illegal) -

```
int r = 10;

if (x >= 0){
  double r = Math.sqrt(x);
}
```

Example 2 (legal) -

```
if (x >= 0){
  double r = Math.sqrt(x);
}

else {
  float r = 0;
}

r = 0;
```

As mentioned above, Example 1 is illegal while Example 2 is not. I'm hoping someone can explain why.

Comment: Example 2 is also illegal according to my compiler, since `r` cannot be resolved as a variable.

Comment: because you cannot name two variable the same

Comment: Please post better examples. Both of them don't compile because `x` is not defined anywhere and in example 2 the outer `r` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: As mentioned above, both of the cases are illegal. It seems like you are trying to do "javascript" tricks in Java.

Answer (score 0):

More context is needed. Your second example is also invalid because r is undefined for the line `r = 0;`.

In general though, block-scope variables cannot collide with method-scoped variables. Block-scoped variables are decalred in code blocks like while or for loops and withing if/else blocks.

In your first example `int r` is your method-scoped variable and `double r` is block-scope. They collide because they have the same name so the compiler rejects it.

In your second example `double r` and `float r` are in separate block-scopes so they don't collide. `r=0` is ambigious, and by the code you've provided should fail with a "cannot find symbol" compiler error. If it's not failing you must have declared it in a different scope and not given us that information.

This is all separate from class variables. Method variables are allowed to collide with class variables. Inside a method where a class and method share a variable name, the method-scope variable is assumed unless you specify the class-scope variable with `this`. For example:

```
public class MyClass{
    int r = 10;

    public void printR(int x) {
        double r = 20.0;

        System.out.println(r); // Prints 20.0
        System.out.println(this.r); // Prints 10
    }
}
```